# vue: error: Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, vue.js

error: Parsing error: Unexpected token

I got this error:

[parsing error-chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcFyh.png)

[parsing error-vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooxxK.png)

But,the error shows:
[expected ','](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofrM5.png)

```
 const fetchUsers (context, userId) => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('/', {
          query: getUsers,
          variables: {
            id: userId
          } 
        })
        console.log('RESP POST:', response.data.data)
        console.log(response.data.data.userById)
        return response
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
```

Comment: even your editor shows you the error, remove the semicolon `;`

Comment: Please post your error and your code directly. Some people cannot access imgur.

Comment: You forgot the function keyword in your definition

Comment: Please show your code directly instead of a picture.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the function keyword:

```
async function fetchUsers (context, userId) {
  // body of function here
}
```

Alternatively you can use the fat arrow syntax:

```
const fetchUsers = async (context, userId) => {
  // body of function here.
}
```

Comment: Thx Ed Hinchliffe!